# Replacing nodes of different kinds - removing wrapping block, leaving only inner expression

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

In CodeFixProvider I need to remove wrapping if-condition (for example):

```
if (temp == null)
{
    temp = new Temp();  
}
```

and I want to leave only adjusted inner expression:

```
// I want to change the inner expression as well
temp = anotherTemp()
```

As soon as I attempt to replace nodes of 'if-block' with line-line statement, 'unable to cast' exception is thrown.
Do you know proper way to do it?

Comment: Show us your code and the exact error.

Comment: I have posted my solution as an answer, but 'unable to cast' exception will emerge anytime you will replace nodes of different kinds. It makes sense actually, only i do not know how to procede. But as @Jeroen Vannevel mentioned, DocumentEditor should be the answer. I remember that I had the same problem with it, but maybe I made a mistake somewhere. Iwill check it and write here if I find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I have found out is to insert adjusted inner expression before if-condition block and remove that block afterwards.
To do that successfuly, you have to track parent block node, otherwise it wont work.

```
  IfStatementSyntax originalIfStatement = parentIfStatement;
  root = root.TrackNodes(originalParentIfStatement);
  parentIfStatement = root.GetCurrentNode(originalParentIfStatement);
  root = root.InsertNodesBefore(parentIfStatement, new[] { SyntaxFactory.ExpressionStatement(newExpression) });
  parentIfStatement = root.GetCurrentNode(originalParentIfStatement);
  root = root.RemoveNode(parentIfStatement, SyntaxRemoveOptions.KeepNoTrivia);
```

If anybodody see any mistake, please, tell me.

Comment: Take a look at the `DocumentEditor` which allows you to easily perform multiple modifications to a tree.

Comment: I know, but in the end, you cannot just replace the nodes, or can you?

Comment: Look at the API it provides. Yes, you can.